# Why doesn't selenium WebDriver launch Firefox on MAC?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Firefox browser does not launch for following configuration
selenium-webdriver-2.43.0
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro11,3
Processor Name: Intel Core i7
System Version: OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Kernel Version: Darwin 13.3.0

Firefox version 32

I have tried downgrading the Firefox version but it does not work.

I am using very basic script:

```
require ‘selenium-webdriver’

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Selenium Tutorials"
element.submit

driver.quit
```

Comment: There was a bug that was fixed. Sounded like java client worked. You can find the issue at: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7642

Comment: I am using selenium-webdriver-2.43.0 which seems mentioned to have fixed the issue. But I am still facing the issue with this particular MAC version.